# updating a dictionary leaves out over 600 key value pairs

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to collect the results of a cosine similarity calculation within a dictionary.
I've compared 95x249 items, which should result in 23655 results. I've checked that via generating  a list of results, which is in deed of length 23655. When I try to do that within a dictionary, I get a length of 22979, hence 676 results are missing. I wonder why that is, has it something to do with how update() works?

Here, I've tried to give a minimal working example:

```
for wordvector1 in words1:
 for wordvector2 in words2:
         dot = numpy.dot(wordvector1, wordvector2)
         norm_o = numpy.linalg.norm(wordvector1)
         norm_r = numpy.linalg.norm(wordvector2)
         cosine = dot / (norm_o * norm_r)
         cosine_sim.append(cosine)
         dict_of_sims.update({cosine:[o_key,r_key]})
```

when I print the results, I get the values added as comments:

```
print(len(dict_of_sims)) #22979 
print(len(cosine_sim)) #23655
print(len(words1)) #95
print(len(words2)) #249
```

Any hint or explanation is highly appreciated!

Comment: what would be the output if you run this? ```len(set(cosine_sim))```

Comment: Hypothesis [for the above test]: There are duplicate keys, last value wins.

Comment: @Hozayafa El Rifai  thank you! the output is also 22979.

Comment: @user2864740 thank you! duplicate keys make sense in my case. is there a way to avoid that the duplicates will be disregarded?

Comment: ok, did a bit research, I cant have duplicate keys bec it would be useless for later retrieving the values. I have to check whether my list as value contains all values

Comment: @user2864740 was faster than me, as you see, you have duplicates :). I hope that helped.

Comment: yes, thank you! I'm trying to find out now, how I add the values in the list instead of loosing them.

Comment: Don't use `update`. You want something like `dict_of_sims.setdefault(cosine, []).append([o_key, r_key])`.